# Why do firemonkey controls always claim to have a child control on iOS?

Tags: ios, delphi, infinite-loop, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I'm working on dynamically creating controls (`TImageControl`) inside of a panel (and as part of trial/error, other container controls). Part of it, I have a piece of code which clears out the old images first:

```
procedure TfrmImageView.Clear;
begin
  while sbImages.ControlsCount > 0 do
    sbImages.Controls[0].DisposeOf;
end;
```

This works perfectly on Windows. However, when I run it on an iPad, it gets stuck in a continuous loop, because for some reason `ControlsCount` is always 1. In fact, this happens even when I have never put any controls in there in the first place.

Why is this reporting always 1 control?

Comment: PS - Solved by storing references in a list, but still curious why does it always say there's one control.

Comment: If you go and take a look at the class name of that panels first child control with `Panel1.Controls[0].ClassName;` you will find out that the class name of that control is TStyledPresentation which is a base control needed for components style system to work. Infact if you do similar check for other FMX components you will get similar results.

Comment: Also your code is potentially dangerous because you are typecasting the panels child controls as being TImageControl which is not good. Why? Ask yourself what would happen if you place some other component on your panel. You would be trying to access that component using wrong class interface which could lead to data being read and written in wrong manner and could thus lead to various unforeseen consequences. Such bugs can be quite hard to track down.

Comment: @SilverWarior I'm casting it as `TImageControl` only for trials figuring out the problem, because at that point I didn't think they were really being destroyed. Originally that wasn't there. It also used to be `.Free`.

Comment: The cast is odd. DisposeOf is from TObject. Use checked casts.

Comment: @David That too was result of trial/error. Here, I'll fix all that...

Comment: Well this code now using `Free` is no more working on ARC-Platforms ...

Comment: @SirRufo Wow, I guess I really need to look even deeper into how Firemonkey works on different platforms. It's a shame that it's not a straight-forward one-for-all fundamental similar to VCL as Emba claims it to be...